# How to get the version of an installed program in windows using chef.

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to get the version of program that is installed on a windows server and I want it as a variable inside the recipe.

Basically I'm trying to find the version and if it is not what I want it will be removed and the correct version of the program will be installed.

I can't figure out a way to get the version though.

The program I want the version for is the Datadog agent.

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing the code, you need to look around in Widows "registry" using "regedit" and find the exact registry key value for the software.

Below example shows, how to fetch the version number of "internet explorer".

Also recommended to have basic knowledge on Ruby array and hash, to understand the code

I've used registry_key_XXXXX Chef methods.

```
if registry_key_exists?('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer')
  subkey_array = registry_get_values('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer')
  Chef::Log.info("#{subkey_array}")
  reg_key_hash = subkey_array.at(-3)
  ver = reg_key_hash.values_at(:data)
  ie_version = ver.to_s[2, 2]
  Chef::Log.warn("IE version #{ie_version}")
else
  Chef::Log.warn("IE Registry key not found")
  return
end
```

Note: Registry key entry may differ for Windows 32bit and 64bit